# Invisible DataTemplate/Grouped GridView row?

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-8

I need to make a DataTemplate for a GridView that's completely invisible; as in, if you hovered over the item it wouldn't show the hover color.

I've tried just using a blank datatemplate like:

```
<DataTemplate>
</DataTemplate>
```

But, while it doesn't show anything, it still shows an outline of the item when you put your mouse over it.

How can I get rid of that outline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need custom style for GridViewItem, and set GridView.ItemContainerStyle to this custom style.
You can find xaml for default styles on your machine here: Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\WinRT\Xaml\Design\ (the path is a bit different for x64)

Comment: THANK YOU :D this was the perfect solution. I was able to use a custom StyleSelector that returns the right style. Thanks again!